# Oracle Date Field is not sorting correctly

Tags: oracle, sorting, date, format

I have a column in oracle, the column type is "DATE", I am 100% sure of this. However when I run the query, it is not producing the correct result. I cannot for the life of me find anything different about the dates that are not working.

I'm looking for any suggestions on hidden oracle setting that might indicate a difference between these rows that I cannot see here.

Thanks

> SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM DATE_TABLE ORDER BY DATE;

```
    DATE        |
--------------------|
2017-02-19 00:00:00 |
2017-02-26 00:00:00 |
2017-03-19 01:00:00 |
2017-03-26 01:00:00 |
2017-03-05 00:00:00 |
2017-03-12 00:00:00 |

2017-03-19 01:00:00 |-2017-03-19 01:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 50,53,3,13,2,1,1 |
2017-03-19 01:00:00 |-2017-03-19 01:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 50,53,3,13,2,1,1 |
2017-03-19 01:00:00 |-2017-03-19 01:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 50,53,3,13,2,1,1 |
2017-03-19 01:00:00 |-2017-03-19 01:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 50,53,3,13,2,1,1 |
2017-03-05 00:00:00 | 2017-03-05 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,5,1,1,1  |
2017-03-05 00:00:00 | 2017-03-05 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,5,1,1,1  |
2017-03-05 00:00:00 | 2017-03-05 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,5,1,1,1  |
2017-03-05 00:00:00 | 2017-03-05 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,5,1,1,1  |
2017-03-12 00:00:00 | 2017-03-12 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,c,1,1,1  |
2017-03-12 00:00:00 | 2017-03-12 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,c,1,1,1  |
2017-03-12 00:00:00 | 2017-03-12 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,c,1,1,1  |
2017-03-12 00:00:00 | 2017-03-12 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,c,1,1,1  |
2017-03-26 00:00:00 | 2017-03-26 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,1a,1,1,1 |
2017-03-26 00:00:00 | 2017-03-26 00:00:00                          |Typ=12 Len=7: 78,75,3,1a,1,1,1 |
```

Comment: I guess it's possible you have some corruption; can you edit your question to add the output of `select date_field, to_char(date_field, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), dump(date_field, 1016) from your_table`, at least for the rows that look odd? If that looks OK is the column indexed - maybe the index is corrupted and rebuilding it might help?

Comment: There is indeed a difference there - Added the output to my initial post. Am I correct in assuming the '-' sign preceeding my date means it was entered as 'BC' ?

Comment: Yep. Maybe not as badly corrupted as I feared (the dump probably isn't useful), but  you'd need to find out how those values were inserted and how they ended up negative/BCE (I assume the time being non-midnight is a flag too?) to see whether/how they can be corrected. Still not sure why 03-26 is sorting before 03-12 based on that though.

Comment: Looks like the 03/19 dates are 2017 B.C., noting the minus (-) sign.  Thus, the date values are in order.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alex, that was the difference I was looking for.